# Algorithm to re-compute the shortest path after edge weight decreases

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Let *d<sub>uv</sub>* be the length of the shortest path from *u* to *v* in a directed graph. Suppose that the length of a single edge *(x, y)* decreases from *c<sub>xy</sub>* to *c'<sub>xy</sub>*. Design an algorithm to recompute all the *d<sub>uv</sub>*'s in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. I don't understand why I wouldn't be able to just recalculate all edge weights. I [can do it](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall11/rec/rec19.pdf) in O(E+V) which is less than O(n<sup>2</sup>) by top-sorting and relaxing edges.

Comment: Any attempt from your side?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: This is not the homework help hotline. Show your work. Here.

Comment: What's n? And how are you supposed to do a topological sort on a potentially-cyclic graph?

Comment: Thats a good point about the potentially cyclic graph, I didnt think about that. I believe n is meant to be E+V.